# Clarification on POST multipart request with python requests and urllib2

Tags: python

I am trying to submit a multipart POST request in Python. I looked around and found 2 variations:

- Using 'reqests' (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)
- Using urllib2 (https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#module-urllib2)

I tried both of them and am able to submit the request successfully.
Below is the sample code for both:

1. ----------requests--------------

   ```
   resp = requests.post(submiturl, files=multipart_form_data, headers=headers,timeout=5)
   ```

   where multipart_form_data contains my file object as well as string parameters
2. ---------------urllib2------------

   ```
   items.append(MultipartParam(name, value))
   fileObj = open(inputFile,'r')
   items.append(MultipartParam('file', filename=inputFile, fileobj=fileObj))
   res = urllib2.urlopen(request)
   ```

My Question:

1. Which one should I use?
2. Correct me if I am wrong but I have seen that while submitting **with urllib2 I get the HTTPError for response code like 500**. However, **while using "request" it does not throw the HTTPError for response code like 500**s instead I have to manually add the condition:

   ```
   Response.raise_for_status():
   ```

   or:

   ```
   resp.status_code != 200: raise Execption(...)
   ```

   Is this correct or I am missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: This is an opinion based question, but **requests** is one of the most used Python libraries out there. The *raise_for_status* thing gives you a chance to inspect the HTTP response and retry if appropriate, which it often is.

Comment: @cbare. `Response.raise_for_status()` will it raise error for anything other than status code 200? Also, can you confirm that urllib2 will throw HTTPError in all the scenarios except 200? If that's the case then I can use urllib2 instead of using "requests" and adding Response.raise_for_status()

Answer (score 0):

[Response.raise_for_status()](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status) raises for HTTP response code in the 4xx and 5xx ranges. The [src](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/models/#Response.raise_for_status) is very clear and readable.

You'll get a 2xx response for successful requests, but you may also want to consider other response codes, for example redirects.

Comment: Do you know if urllib2 will raise HTTP error for everything other than 200?